# Xcode can't change View Controller

Tags: xcode, pushviewcontroller

```
let profileViewController = 
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"ProfileViewcontroller") as! ProfileViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, 
animated: true)
```

http://prntscr.com/i87reg

Don't understand, why it isset working.

Comment: Is the `navigationController` nil?

Comment: because you don't have checked the "Use Storyboard ID".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try initializing storyboard ?

Either storyboard or navigationController is nil.

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", Bundle: Bundle.main) 
 let profileViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewcontroller") as! ProfileViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I uploaded all my files, [here](https://ufile.io/4zwap) because its really just a project but, most of it is copied from [Xcode Login Screen Example](https://www.simplifiedios.net/xcode-login-screen-example/#Creating_Profile_ViewController). But i wanted to make the UI from the bottom. I tried your code, but no success.

Comment: Please embed your first (Login) view controller in Navigation Controller. The issue was with your navigation controller as well. Please see the images attached in my original answer.

Comment: Select View Controller > Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller. Use the same code to initialise the storyboard and this should work.

Comment: O. M. G. Thanks. The reason i did not use the example was because i did not want the navigation bar, but i can hide it. Thanks for the help.